# How to move x units between given 2 vertices of an undirected graph?

Tags: graph

Start - can keep all x units.
End -  can keep all x units.
Any other vertice can keep only 1 unit/turn. The edges can't keep units between turns.

Roy-Floyd don't work because it gives me the shortest route between Start and End, but I want them all.
Backtracking is not good also because it takes ages to complete on a 300+ edges graph, so I'm looking for an algorithm.

Comment: "shortest route between Start and End, but I want them all", why do you want them all? Won't you use the shortest path only always?

Comment: But in any case, if you want shortest paths between all pairs, consider: Floyd Warshall, if O(V^3) works for you.